# How to launch SSRS report on demand

Tags: sql-server-2014-express, ssrs-2014

We have an application that is inserting data to the SQL Server data base. I have to create a report based on the data from this SQL Server data base.The report should be generated on a demand (by a user click from the application) as a HTML file and saved in a specific folder on a PC.

I think the best way is to use SSRS, but I'm not so familiar with it. I've created a report using Report Builder tool.

How can I create the report on demand each time the user requires it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a back-end running on C# to consume SSRS web service. Along with this you will also need to have a .rdl file (template/design) for representing that sql-data.

On click of the button/link you can have a server call to generate that report for you.

Refer : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tutorials/access-report-server-web-service-vb-vcsharp-ssrs-tutorial?view=sql-server-2014

and https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1110411/How-to-Write-a-Csharp-Wrapper-Class-for-the-SSRS-R

Comment: I would like to avoid creating an additional application. I'm looking for a way to use SQL trigger to generate that report.

Comment: I guess you need a application anyway to interact with sql for triggering any action unless it is a recurring job which can be scheduled using sql server agent.

Comment: I suppose that if it can be done using SQL job (I hope, I understand you correctly), it also can be done using SQL trigger. How it can be done by SQL server agent? Thank you, vS12

Comment: You have a option in sql server agent where you can ask sql server to executed a script or a procedure at a particular time everyday, at a particular time. Search for scheduling using sql server agent. And because it is a one time setup, someone has to do this and then reports will be generated depending on the schedule. For calling trigger script also you'll need a backend running.

Comment: So, I have .rdl file . What procedure/script should I create in order to generate a report based on .rdl file I have? It is exactly what I need to figure out. Thanks,vS12

Comment: While creative . Rdl itself, you define the script or procedure from which the report fields would come from and then the same script is executed. Or if you are building the .rdl itself programmatically then you have the option of defining the script which should be executed.